# How to properly indent the while loop in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I started learning python last week. I have very weak background in programming as I did C++ before but poorly. I started python and wanted to make a complex calculator. I am trying to learn restrictions and if statements better so I decided to make the calculator for positive values only.
However, upon making this statement. The message appears, but the calculated value also appears.
Here is the code:

```
  op = ""
while op != "#":
     num1 = float(input("Enter your first number:"))
     op = input("Enter an operator: ")
     num2 = float(input("Enter your second number: "))

     if num1 < 0 or num2 < 0:
      print("Calculator accepts positive values only")
     if op == "+":
      print(num1+num2)
     elif op=="-":
      print(num1-num2)
     elif op=="*":
      print(num1*num2)
     elif op=="/":
      print(num1/num2)
     else:
      print("end of program")
```

How to remove the out put of the calculated number? I want the program to restart the loop when I enter negative numbers
Is there a way to "break" the loop then re-do it again?
I humbly apologize if this is a very trivial question, I recently started, and would love to learn from experienced users here on stackoverflow.

Comment: You don't have a loop here! You need to properly indent your code, especially when asking questions here as we can't assume you've got it right!

Comment: Also.. is there a reason you only want to accept positive numbers? it works perfectly well with negative numbers, so why the arbitrary restriction?

Comment: To answer your question... if you make the second 'if' an 'elif' it will skip calculating and start again if they enter a negative.  is that what you want?

Comment: Hi, I edited the code, I hope its better now. I just want it to be in positive numbers just so I can test a way of breaking a loop with a restriction without ending the program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`break` and `continue` are the operators you are looking for

https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/break-continue

`break` will stop a loop entirely, `continue` will stop the current iteration of the loop and go onto the next one.

```
op = ""
while op != "#":
  
    num1 = float(input("Enter your first number:"))
    op = input("Enter an operator: ")
    num2 = float(input("Enter your second number: "))

    if num1 < 0 or num2 < 0:
        print("Calculator accepts positive values only")
        continue #start again
    
    if op == "STOP":
        break #quit

    if op == "+":
        print(num1+num2)
```

Answer (score 1):

All you really need to do is wrap the if statements in an else loop.

```python
op = ""
while op != "#":
    num1 = float(input("Enter your first number:"))
    op = input("Enter an operator: ")
    num2 = float(input("Enter your second number: "))

    if num1 < 0 or num2 < 0:
        print("Calculator accepts positive values only")
    else:
        if op == "+":
            print(num1+num2)
        elif op=="-":
            print(num1-num2)
        elif op=="*":
            print(num1*num2)
        elif op=="/":
            print(num1/num2)
        else:
            print("end of program")
```

The first if statement checks if the number is positive or not. If it is negative, the loop restarts, however, if it is positive, it tests what the operators are equal to.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is displaying the message along with the ans when you enter a negative value because the condition if op == '+' should be elif op == '+'. Its because it checks the first condition which is true so it prints the message but since the 2nd condition has if as well, it comes out to be true if your operator is + and thus the ans is being displayed. Here's how the correct code would look like:

```
op = ""

while op != "#":
  num1 = float(input("Enter your first number:"))
  op = input("Enter an operator: ")
  num2 = float(input("Enter your second number: "))

  if num1 < 0 or num2 < 0:
      print("Calculator accepts positive values only")
  elif op == "+":
      print(num1+num2)
  elif op=="-":
      print(num1-num2)
  elif op=="*":
      print(num1*num2)
  elif op=="/":
      print(num1/num2)
  else:
      print("end of program")
```